# socket io cross domain security

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Im using socket io over a regular http connection as so :

```
`socket =  io.connect('http://example.com')`;
```

I was wondering how could I secure this, so someone can't make a cross-domain connection from another server (for example they connect from `http://someone.com` to `http://example.com` . Would I use https and `{secure: true}`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use authorize every connection to my sockets.. something like in this

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

In addition to that I would set a token cookie on to the client before making the socket connection that I will authorize in the authorization block. Something like checking the logged in user cookie or something will help.

Comment: In addition to that you can also verify the incoming header's url inside the authorization socket handshake.. and see if it is in your domain.

Comment: I was reading that cross domain connections were not allowed if jsonp polling was not enabled. or access control allow origin was not set to *